# Android TextView text gravity for Hebrew works in Emulator, but not on Device

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got TextView and I set propery `android:gravity="right"` for Hebrew text, that works in Emulator, but not on device. On device text is aligned left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this answer [Android setting with TextView for Hebrew text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6302221/509498)