# How to make the text direction from right to left

Tags: android, textview, right-to-left

I want to write text in (right to left language i.e. Arabic) in a TextView. But I want to make the text writing direction from right to left. `gravity:right`will align the text to right only. I want to justify the text from right to left ( to make the words and numbers appear in he entered order in the line ) . how ?

Comment: I believe this answers your question. It's marked as correct... I haven't tested it to verify that it is *indeed correct, but it looks like it should work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302221/android-setting-problem-with-textview-for-hebrew-text

Comment: how to set Try adding a RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK character (\u200F)  ??  such this >> tv.setText("\u200F My Arabic text");

Comment: I think so, as I said, I hadn't tried it, but that does look like the correct approach

Answer (score 69):

Another clever way which can be used in older versions of android and can be used anywhere in string so it's handier even in latest version of android, is to include the **right-to-left mark** or even **left-to-right mark** in the string when it's needed:

```
left-to-right mark: &lrm; or &#x200e; (U+200E)
right-to-left mark: &rlm; or &#x200f; (U+200F)
```

This is how it's down:

```
String rtl = "Hello \u200F(سلام)";
```

The good thing about this method is you can even use it after **punctuation like (,{,[,!** which are positioned right incorrectly! examples:

```
سلام! // wrong position
سلام!‏ // right position by adding RLM after !
```

look how **!** is positioned correctly in second line, actually there is an RLM after it, and you can copy paste it even if it's invisible.

The second good thing as you saw it is that you can use this method (these char codes) in any system that supports RTL like browsers, word and so on.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati These chars are added to UTF exactly for this purpose, so as long as rendering engine respect them there will be no side effect, which is the case in android. The only thing is, in some fonts a representation glyph exist for these codes, and they are displayed when these chars are used. you must remove their glyphs using some font editor tools like font creator.

Comment: life-saving. Thanks

Answer (score 52):

Just put this property in your TextView and everything will workout just fine it will automatically detect your text and change accordingly

```
android:textDirection="anyRtl"
```

Comment: `Attribute "textDirection" is only used in API level 17 and higher (current min is 13)`

Comment: If the above didn't work try `android:textAlignment="viewStart"`

Answer (score 21):

Too late , but the `android:gravity="right"` worked.

Comment: this will mess up mixed text, numbering, braces etc.
definitely use android:gravity="right" /see:
http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

Comment: It will affect if you use English text

Answer (score 19):

set this line in *xml* for textview :

```
 android:textDirection="locale"
```

Comment: and sets text as for Arabic ...myTextView.settext("\u200F"+"text").

Comment: I have seperate xml layout for arabic designs

Comment: For me, all Arabic texts were showing right to left properly. But when the text started with an English word (rest of the text was Arabic), it was showing left to right..
android:textDirection="locale" -> 
this line solved it for me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 17):

Try using

```
 textview.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

or

```
 textview.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL);
```

Comment: what are the differences?

Answer (score 7):

In case of normal edit text this will work

```
      android:textDirection="rtl"
```

But in case of password fields this is not enough then follow this;

```
     android:textDirection="rtl"
     android:gravity="right"
```

Comment: For me it was crucial using `android:textDirection="anyRtl"` instead of using simply `rtl` additionally to your suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

Use `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` and `android:textAlignment="viewStart"` to make the text view right-to-left.

Answer (score 3):

try this as it worked for me `android:textDirection="rtl"`

Answer (score 3):

Add these to your editText:

```
android:gravity="right"
android:textDirection="rtl"
```

PS: `android:textDirection` requires API level 17

Answer (score 0):

just adding my own experience with such issues. in my case in addition to suggested solutions i also had to replace English " character with the RTL (in my case hebrew) representation of such character ״

Answer (score 0):

By using attributes as below in my xml code strangely I got a right to left  text with correct punctuation. But this is not a perfect solution for multi language text:

```
android:textDirection="ltr"
android:gravity="right"
```

setting ltr corrects punctuation problems like having dot on right side instead of left.

gravity attribute makes text flow from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

best way textDirection for TextView, **Don't use layoutDirection**

```
  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/viewCountTv"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textDirection="anyRtl"
     android:gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: Can you provide more info in why not to use `layoutDirection` ?