# android java how to append a text in new line from the right side

Tags: java, android

I want to append a text to String after adding new line starting from right to left in my android app
example:

```
String g= "مرحبا";
g.append("\n اهلا");
```

so here the text start from the left, note that i am using a textView to display this String.

Comment: Does `Sring` class have `append()`? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what result you want use one of these in the `TextView`s Layout:

```
android:textDirection="anyRtl"
```

(this sets text layout to Right-to-left)

```
android:gravity="right"
```

(this aligns the text on the right)

I think if you want to have some lines left and some right you could use html markup, but I'm not sure about that.

For other methods see [How to make the text direction from right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964488/how-to-make-the-text-direction-from-right-to-left)

Comment: thanks this worked for me specially android:gravity="right"