# Problems with changing the Language | blocking widget places

Tags: android, localization, local

I can add Layout-ar or Values-ar. And I can manage every thing. **But, the problem is:**

When the language transfer to Arabic. Every thing will be from right to left. My Taps is from left to right in default. But when the language be arabic. The tabs transfer to (From right to left !). And the biggest problem is the style !.

Like custom list view, Tablayout, The Places of the buttons. **Everything goes wrong.**

**Help!**

**Note: Is there anyway to block the widgets places ?**

Comment: Do you want to block right-to-left of only widgets, but not text? Have you checked <application> android:supportsRtl=["true" | "false"] attribute in your manifest?

Comment: I want to block the widgets, Tabs, the way to swipe in fragments....

I only want to make the text from right to left I think

Comment: android:supportsRtl="true"

Comment: I make it False.. And It Works !!! Thanks very Much Bro !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could block right-to-left support using `<application> android:supportsRtl=["true" | "false"] tag`. It's described under [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#supportsrtl) .
Note that it's available only from API 17. Description of the attribute is not completely clear, so it might be better to test on real devices first.

Answer (score 0):

Arabic is started from `right to left` and other languages start from `left to right.`

You need to understand that.

If you need any changes, you must have to use **custom css for arabic**.
For android related issue, you can use Bidi.
Link:

1. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Bidi.html
2. [How to make the text direction from right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964488/how-to-make-the-text-direction-from-right-to-left)

**UPDATE:**

I got your point. If you want to block
in app `AndroidManifest.xml` add `android:supportsRtl="false"`

```
application
    android:name=".CustomApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="false">
```

For better understanding, follow the tutorial.

1. https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/issues/386
2. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

Comment: My mother language is Arabic. So, I know it perfect. My problem is with my application widget's places

Comment: @Besho I have given you 2 links. Please check. Hope it will give you quell

Comment: I want it in android. And I don't prefer to use HTML Or Css in android. I read an article about adding them and the negative of adding them

Comment: @Besho I want to suggest you Bidi. Please check android related link that I provided.

Comment: I think that you didn't read my question well. My problem is that when I added the Folders-AR. The widgets go right to left. I want to block the widget places in default language and in Arabic Language]