# How to change text direction in excel cell using java poi?

Tags: java, excel, text, apache-poi, direction

I want to change **Text_Direction** (not Alignment) of a single **cell** (not worksheet) on an excel file using java Apache_**poi** library.
how can I do it? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after looking a lot I found another way that will fix the problem.
As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30415888/6914931) , it's just needed to change the direction of the text that will be placed in the cell.
the solution will be like below for right to left:

```
String rtl = "\u200F" + otherTexts;
```

and like this for LTR:

```
String left2right_text = "\u200E" + otherTexts;
```