# I want to write from right hand side to left hand side in textview

Tags: android

I want to write from right hand side to left hand side in textview.So please tell me how should i do that.

```
            <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/dl_discount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dl_price"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dl_price"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dl_price"
            android:text="1" />
```

Comment: Please check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964488/how-to-make-the-text-direction-from-right-to-left

Comment: i tried it many times that had been descripted in link provided by you...but its not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the text direction from right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964488/how-to-make-the-text-direction-from-right-to-left)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set `android:textDirection` to rtl

Comment: @Egaragee did you accept an answer that is not working to you ? If so, please discard the accepted answer and provide information on what's happening instead.