# android EditText android:textDirection

Tags: android, android-edittext, direction

I'd like to set an EditText to be LTR at all times, how do I do that?
android:textDirection does seem to be the answer, i cant get the project to compile with that directive

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6302325/1337412

Comment: adding the unicode LTR mark does seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding \u202D (LTR OVERRIDE) to the beginning of the string does the trick

Answer (score 5):

use gravity for the editText

```
android:gravity="right"
```

Comment: I think OP means LTR as in Arabic language, not as aligned to the right.

Comment: but when you aligned the arabic text to right its will appear correctly. im an arabic developer

Comment: aligning to the right would work if I wanted RTL text.
what I need is LTR directional text.
a text that's aligned to the left and in case the chars "aa bb" are inserted the Edit text the text should display "aa bb" and not "bb aa" which is the case when using an RTL language (Hebrew in my case).

Answer (score 0):

use direction for the editText

```
android:textDirection="ltr"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these to your `EditText`:

```
android:gravity="left"
android:textDirection="ltr"
```

Note: `android:textDirection` requires API level 17