# EditText force textDirection to ltr doesn't work, can any body advice?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I have an edit text field, which I need to format every word to hashtag

> Example if I type `ABC`  it should be formatted to `#ABC`

I’ve implemented it with input filter but I’m not able to manage it when user enter Arabic text, `#abc# مرحبا #مرحبا`  appears like this,  I assume I can solve the problem if I can force the EditText `android:textDirection="ltr"`, but even after this change android EditText behaving `rtl` when input is Arabic text.

So my question is, how to force an EditText to behave `ltr` even for `rtl` text inputs like Arabic?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763508/android-edittext-androidtextdirection

Answer (score 0):

To make for both direction automatically use below codes

```
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:textAlignment="viewStart"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer it on the following site for more description [Very nice blog by: Sven Bendel](https://ubuntudroid.github.io/2015/01/11/handling-ltr-text-in-rtl-environments.html) or [his github page](https://github.com/ubuntudroid)

```
/**
     * Reformat the String as LTR to ensure that it is laid out from
     * left to right, but it doesn't affect overall layouting of
     * TextViews etc..
     */
    public static String makeLtr ( String string ) {
       if (checkRtl(string)) {
            /* prepend the string with an LTR control sign (so
               that Android's RTL check returns false) and an RTL
               control sign (so that the string itself is printed in
               RTL) and append an LTR control sign (so that if we
               append another String it is laid out LTR). */
            return "\u200E" + "\u200F" + string + "\u200E";
        } else {
            return string;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the given String is probably written in RTL by
     * checking if the very first character is within the range of
     * RTL unicode characters.
     */
    public static boolean checkRtl ( String string ) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(string)) {
            return false;
        }
        char c = string.charAt(0);
        return c >= 0x590 && c <= 0x6ff;
    }
```