# Is it possible to make the screen orientation of Android app reverse for Arabic, Hebrew on pre-4.2 Android systems

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, right-to-left

I found it hard to find much information online about RTL languages support in Android. **In versions above 4.2 everything seems** to be working perfectly fine. But when I switch to older version I can't make the screen to be with right-to-left orientation.

What I mean is that the TextView that are set to stay left, stay left, etc. I followed the instructions from this link: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

All the things that are written here **doesn't work on pre-4.2 Android.** So is it even possible to make your screen orientation from right to left on this versions or was this option only added in 4.2 and for older versions if you want reversed layout you should write it yourself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746091/how-to-handle-rtl-languages-on-pre-4-2-versions-of-android perhaps have a search first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use Arabic or persian Language you can use PersianReshape Class:

Download This file and Put it in your project(Its a Java File):

http://file.and-share.ir/uploads/and-roid.ir1374338060741.zip

and the usage is like this:

[image]

Comment: I was talking about something like android:supportsRtl="true" which works flawlessly in newer versions of Android. Is there something like that in older versions.

Comment: I don't Think so!! ):