# Android below 4.2 how to set layoutDirection to be RTL

Tags: android, android-layout

trying to set the layout elements to be RTL ordered

in 4.2 and above the line: `layoutDirection="rtl"` and in the manifest: `android:supportsRtl="true"` is working just fine.

but for below 4.2 its not.

solution anyone ?

Comment: Can you found a solution?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746091/how-to-handle-rtl-languages-on-pre-4-2-versions-of-android) answer, please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't be able to. It was added to in API Level 17 which is 4.2 so the older versions do not support it.

Comment: so r u suggesting me to change the order of the elements in the xml ?

Comment: Probably the best way you create a layout file for specific android API levels. e.g. ``layout-v17`` so that the new APIs use the RTL layout, then create a layout for older verions that have the XML in the way round you need

Answer (score 24):

Just use **ViewCompat** using android.support.v4.view to do it.

```
ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(findViewById(R.id.my_view), ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

Comment: Magic!! Great solution!

Comment: @ArefBahreini This method work on api 17 and above. Check inside of this method - if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) { view.setLayoutDirection(layoutDirection); }

Answer (score 2):

you can change your application language and solve this problem :

```
String languageToLoad  = "en";
Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```