# Right To Left SnackBar

Tags: android, right-to-left, android-snackbar

I want to display a **text** with an **action** on *Design Support Library SnackBar*. 
My language is writen in Right-to-Left. So how can i change SnackBar text and action direction?

 Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Finally from the answers and more searches i found this solution:

```
Snackbar snackbar =
    Snackbar.make(view, "My right2left text", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                }
             });
```

Set direction to Right-to-Left:

```
ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(snackbar.getView(),ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

Don't forget this for showing the snackbar:

```
snackbar.show();
```

---

**UPDATE**

Since you have `Text` and `Action` as `TextView` you can use the other TextView methods for them. like as `setTypeface()`, `setTextSize()` and so on.

Set typeface for text:

```
TextView text = snackbar.getView().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
text.setTypeface(yourTypeface);
```

Set typeface for action:

```
TextView action = snackbar.getView().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_action);
action.setTypeface(yourTypeface);
```

Comment: Use ViewCompat from android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat for android below 17 

As in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30463608/set-layoutdirection-rtl-for-api-lower-than-17/37670836.

Comment: simple and useful

Comment: You save my day ;)

Answer (score 5):

just add this codes :

In Android manifest under the application tag keep this

android:supportsRtl="true"

and this :

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(getView(), "Text", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    TextView view1 = (TextView)snackbar.getView().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    view1.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
}

snackbar.show();
```

Comment: Ok, But its useful while you want to use RTL direction for your app.
In some cases you want to use LTR direction for the app and RTL for some widgets.

Answer (score 2):

you have to set this based on Local. Android supports this feature.

From Android API Level 17+ it supports RTL natively. To force your entire layout to be RTL including the ActionBar do the following.

In Android manifest under the application tag  keep this

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

defince a method like this in Utils class

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
public static void getRtlSupport() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
    }  
}
```

Use this repo as reference and implement this for snackbar

https://github.com/semsamot/ActionBarRTLizer.git

Comment: Thanks, and what about API Level 17- ? My app min sdk is 14.

Comment: this is not the best practice. better way for avoiding something strange happen to RTL language Lovers in android app development is create custom RTL layout and inflate that on every where across app e.g. toolbar with custom RTL layout has better performance in each API than choose Android RTL Support and force the layout to be RTL. so this is my experience. thanks patient reader

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by set custom layout for snack layout according to this refrence.

[customize snackBar's layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453946/how-to-customize-snackbars-layout)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void showSnackbar(String text, int Length, String Action, View.OnClickListener clickListener) {
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout), text, Length);
    View snack = snackbar.getView();
    snackbar.getView().setRotationY(180);
    snack.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.DarkBlue));
    TextView snack_text = (TextView)snack.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    TextView snack_action = (TextView)snack.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_action);
    snack_text.setTypeface(tf);
    snack_action.setTypeface(tf);
    snack_action.setRotationY(180);
    snack_text.setRotationY(180);
    snackbar.setAction(Action, clickListener);
    snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00c4ff"));
    snackbar.show();
}
```

Comment: Please explain how and why your code solves the problem, because code-only answers are not appreciated at StackOverflow. Also, you could explain, why your answer exceeds the previous older answers (mainly the accepted one).

Answer (score 0):

Only you need:

```
         Snackbar snackbar=Snackbar.make(v, "آیا از حذف کامل این مورد مطمئن هستید؟", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("حذف", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                           //info@giran.ir
                           //09155336168
                        }
                    });
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                View snack = snackbar.getView();
                snack.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
            }

            snackbar.show();
```