# how to left to right toolbar api 16

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-xml, arabic, farsi

I'm using ***NavigationView*** and add ***toolbar*** with ***include*** . I use `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` and all apis works fine but in ***api 16*** it doesn't work.

**So how can i left to right toolbar in api 16?**

drawer_layout.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   android:layoutDirection="rtl"
   tools:openDrawer="end">


   <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/content_frame"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@id/appbar" />

   <include
       android:id="@+id/appbar"
       layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:visibility="visible" />

   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
       android:id="@+id/nav_view"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       android:layoutDirection="rtl"
       app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
       app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: Support for RTL layout direction was included in API 17 and it doesn't work before it. There's no solution.

Comment: you can use multiple layout files to fix this

Comment: @RahulKumar can you explain more please? or give me a link.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately it's not possible to use `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` in API 16 or lower.

`android:layoutDirection="rtl"` was first included in API 17 and higher.

> **If you want more information I definitely recommend to read [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/rtl-support-on-android-here-is-all-you-need-know-e13f2df512e2) article.**

But there is always a solution in programming.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30463608/set-layoutdirection-rtl-for-api-lower-than-17) question is similar to yours and maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to support rtl `Toolbar`s in APIs **below 17**. Try to use a custom `Toolbar` such as [RtlToolbar](https://github.com/alirezaafkar/Toolbar).

**Build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.alirezaafkar:toolbar:1.1.2'
}
```

**layout.xml:**

```
<com.alirezaafkar.toolbar.RtlToolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:direction="rtl"
    app:optionsMenu="@menu/menu_main"
    app:font="@string/font_path"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    app:title="@string/app_name"/>
```

**Result:**

[image]