# How can I change UI programmatically android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library

I'm trying to change UI dynamically based on direction of layout.

I found something like "Native RTL support in Android 4.2"  but supports minSdkVersion 14

So my question is:

Is there any library or solution to do this without do traditional solution that make two layout to support two language?!

thanks..

Comment: Give a look at this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746091/how-to-handle-rtl-languages-on-pre-4-2-versions-of-android

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, read the documentation through better next time. As you can read [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html) you simply create multiple resource files. This goes with the layout folder as well.

Example folder names:

For english layout

```
layout-en
```

and default layout

```
layout
```

Comment: thanks for help but unfortunately I don't want to do this traditional solution ...