# Question mark instead of RTL field

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablelayout, android-toolbar

I used this [Material Design Toolbar](https://github.com/tekinarslan/AndroidMaterialDesignToolbar) for my project.

But I have 2 problems:

1. When I use a RTL String for the Tabs Title, it doesn't show the String correctly

   ```
   private String titles[] = new String[]{"تست", "Sample Tab 2", "Sample Tab 3", "Sample Tab 4"
       , "Sample Tab 5", "Sample Tab 6", "Sample Tab 7", "Sample Tab 8"};
   ```

   Inside OnCreate:

   ```
   mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
   mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navdrawer);
   toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   if (toolbar != null) {
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_ab_drawer);
   }
   pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
   slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
   pager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), titles));
   ```

   This shows:

   [image]

   2. How possible use `android:supportsRtl="true"` in under API 17? or opening material slide menu from right.
      I change the container gravity to `Right` and it opened correctly from Right side whit dragging , but return error with opening via Toggle in Toolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks to `@anil` Finally i find two way for problem :**

1. change source file encoding in `Settings>File Encoding` :

[image]

**if problem not resolve :**

2. **First way** + Using Strings from resources `(R.String.nameOfString)` instead type them directly in Java source code

Answer (score 1):

1. it seems the problem is in source file encoding. Try to change it to utf.
2. first you should make changes described [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html). and as for pre-17 rtl-support see answers: [How to handle RTL languages on pre 4.2 versions of Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746091/how-to-handle-rtl-languages-on-pre-4-2-versions-of-android) and [Identifyng RTL language in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996183/identifyng-rtl-language-in-android)