# In horizontal linearlayout, how to add from left to right instead of right to left

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I think the source of the problem is that my phone language is right-to-left.
So in Android Studio preview, when i try to use horizontal LinearLayout it shows the views im adding from left to right, but running on my phone it switches the order from right to left.
How can i force Linear Layout views to add from left to right?

Comment: Please add some of your code that defines the layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to play with `android:layoutDirection` parameter in your XML layout file to explicitly define the direction of your `Views`

**EDIT**

This feature is available from API 17, so you'll need to implement it differently in earlier versions.

Comment: Thanks! Adding - 
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
solved it

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that according to developer.android it's only available in API 17 and higher:

> Note: To enable right-to-left layout features for your app, you must set supportsRtl to "true" and set targetSdkVersion to 17 or higher.

reference:[Layout direction](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2)

for lower API (which still relevant today) it's a lit bit messy, some of issues (and solutions) discussed here:
[layoutDirection android pre 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746091/how-to-handle-rtl-languages-on-pre-4-2-versions-of-android?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks Nikita, i need help with how can i force the action bar to be "left-to-right" using a menu.xml? i created a menu.xml file with 2 items in it, but the app name is at the right end and the 2 items are in this "three dots" icon. how can i control the action bar layout direction?

Comment: ok thanks i fixed it. just changed - android:supportsRtl="true" to android:supportsRtl="false" in AndroidManfiest.xml under "<application",
and changed in menu.xml  - android:showAsAction="always" to app:showAsAction="always", now its working. Thanks again!