# Android - setLayoutDirection in API 15 and API 16

Tags: android, android-layout, right-to-left, android-api-levels

Does anyone know if `ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection` works in API level *below* 17?

I search for a solution all over the internet but I can't find a solid one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle RTL languages on pre 4.2 versions of Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746091/how-to-handle-rtl-languages-on-pre-4-2-versions-of-android)

Answer (score 3):

`setLayoutDirection` was added to in API Level 17 (read [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#RTL)) which is 4.2 so the older versions do not support that. So keep two layouts for higher and below and you need to work around for the below api level XML view.

If you're using the [support](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html) library, you can do the following:

```
if (ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(view) == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
    //  view -RTL layout
} else {
    //view -  set made layout for below apis 
}
```

[BidiFormatter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/text/BidiFormatter.html) might help you depending on your requirement.Check that as well.

Every one knows about `android:layout_gravity="end"` right? can be helpfull in this case