# How to set Right to Left direction for numbers in Android TextView?

Tags: android, textview, numbers, right-to-left

We need to allow user to enter the numbers from Right to Left in Android TextView, ex: if an user wants to enter the sum of 2 numbers, the user starts adding the ones' place digits first and enter the the ones place result digit first, then tens place etc. Android 4.0 supports RTL languages for Hebrew, Arabic. Is it possible to implement a Custom TextView to allow user to enter only numbers from Right to Left direction or is any other UI component is available directly?

Answer (score 5):

It seems this little trick is working on all devices, add this unicode character at the beginning of your text inside your `TextView` or your `EditText` to let the users input from right to left: `\u200F`.

You can also have a look to this specific [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302221/android-setting-with-textview-for-hebrew-text/6302325#6302325) that looks like yours.

Comment: How can we set the text direction from bottom to up. like (from bottom to up)'K' 'A' 'R' 'T' 'H' 'I' in TextView.