# Custom Softkeyboard urdu set Cursor Right side

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have created custom softkeyboard for urdu language. it's working fine.

As per urdu language It cursor should start from right side of editbox.

But when I use that keyboard in device  in some applications it starts from left side i.e whatsup. and in some application cursor start from right side. i.e. inbuilt message application.

What code should I do in application so that in every application cursor starts from right side?

Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is no way to do this. It depends on app and system.

Answer (score 1):

Which Android version are you using?

Since Android 4.1, it supports for bidirectional text in EditText element so that Edittext RTL or LTR type is converted automatically when one sets the system language. I tested with Kurdish and Farsi language and it works fine. I am not sure about Urdu language though.

For Android version below 4.1, I think it depends on the manufacturers. They had to change Android framework source to support RTL.

Android 4.2 has more features regarding RTL support such as RTL layout mirroring. Check out this article: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

Hope this helps.

I found a little trick for RTL-support TextView here:
[Android setting with TextView for Hebrew text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302221/android-setting-with-textview-for-hebrew-text/6302325#6302325)