# Android strings.xml resource - arabic language and dynamic formatted strings

Tags: android, string, resources, arabic, formatted

Hello I have a question about arabic formatting how should I properly format this strings, it seems i can't manage this:

```
تحميل %1$s&#8230;

تم تحميل الكلمات. %1$d/%2$d!
```

This is in sublime text 2 - but i think that there is Left-to-Right order

[image]

EDITED: 
In Eclipse this copied from Sublime Text gets messed up a little. I hire some person to translate from english to arabic strings.xml. He used Word editor but things get messed up when coping to eclipse and I suggested to changed it in Sublime Text, that I think will support it correctly like in Eclipse and is lighter editor. I see that in Sublime Text seems to be in Left-To-Right order which is also wrong. 
*** When I run app with this messed up special characters it seems to run correctly. Bu I have doubt whether some interpunction words hasn't also messed up and for example: Item 5/10 has been downloaded. will be Item has been downloaded. 5/10 or something like this.*** 
Need a preferred way to get someone english written strings.xml, get this translated, and then copied into /values-ar and working correctly? 
[image]

Comment: why are you using sublime text ? how does the file look in eclipse/android studio

Answer (score 9):

Try adding a RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK character (\u200F) at the start of your text.

similar type answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302221/android-setting-with-textview-for-hebrew-text)

Comment: Thanks! I used to have a lot of problems with Arabic texts starting with a word in English. (The app in which I work needs this in some moments). This works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

That is a sublime issue with Right-to-Left languages as listed [here](https://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/37207-right-to-left-languages-support/). You dont have to worry too much about it because it does not affect the results, your app will show it perfectly.

Comment: seems to be right but I will be checking further whether some order of words didn't changed

Comment: for the changing of variable places in translations, I think this is  the job of the translator. Each language has its structure.

Comment: yes this is the job of the translator but sending it in some document via internet, copying between several editors and it has 3 different structure of the sentence, for me this arabic chars are meaning nothing :)

Answer (score 3):

"To solve this problem, use the unicodeWrap() method, found in the BidiFormatter class, on every piece of text that you insert into a localized message."

Quoted from here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html#FormatText

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Arabic Font` like:

```
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/arabic_letters.TTF");
yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextVIew);
yourTextView.setTypeface(face, Typeface.BOLD);
```