# Fatal Exception: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException Conversion: מ

Tags: java, android, character-encoding, string-formatting, right-to-left

This code gives error on String.format(...):

```
inviterNameTitleView.setText(
                String.format(
                        context.getString(R.string.sharing_invite_title),
                        inviter.getNameForTitle()
                )
        );
```

`R.string.sharing_invite_title` is `<string name="sharing_invite_title">%s invites you to smth.</string>`

What could be the reason of this error? The symbol that results in error is a right-to-left alphabet letter. Googling doesn't give any answers.

Comment: So `String.format("%s invites you to:", inviter.getNameForTitle());` works ?

Comment: I quickly implemented this and set the right-to-left alphabet letter directly. Everything was fine for me =( Can't explain why there is an error for you. Even when using the string-resource directly and not inside a String.format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that the app crashed only when on Hebrew locale, which was with `iw` code (not on `he`), which was weird to have the old code on Android 5.0. The corresponding string in strings file had `s%` instead of `%s`. That gave the `UnknownFormatConversionException`.

This happens because of lack of RTL support in Android Studio. See more detailed answer in this question: [Android strings.xml resource - arabic language and dynamic formatted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29071623/231590)

Comment: Same for Arabic, and it seems for any RTL string

Answer (score 1):

Replace % with \u0025

% is a special character in xml. So you should not directly place it.

Comment: But `%s` was supposed to be replaced by `inviter.getNameForTitle()`.