# can't read hebrew letters from text file in raw resource - java

Tags: android, hebrew

I did a lot of trials but cannot read hebrew letters from raw resource text file.
Every time I try I get squars with ?. If I'm reading English letters everything is OK.
I tried also using UTF-8 and I got gibirish too.

Here is the code that I'm using.

```
InputStream inStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.questutf8);

if (inStream != null)
{    
   InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(inStream);

   int c, i=0;
   int i=0;
   char [] cb = new char[1];
   byte [] buf = new byte[100];
   String line;

   while (inputReader.read(cb, 0, 1) > -1)
   {

      if(cb[0] == '\r' || cb[0] == '\n')
      {

          line = new String(buf, 0, i, "UTF-8");
          i=0;

    //Doing somthing with line
      }

      else
      {

          buf[i++] = (byte) cb[0];
      }

   }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what should I do?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: What is the encoding of the source text file?

Answer (score 0):

If the source file is UTF-8, try using the [InputStreamReader(InputStream, String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) constructor to pass in the encoding and read the file in UTF-8:

```
InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(inStream, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: the encoding of the source file in this case is UTF-8.

Comment: the encoding of the source file in this case is UTF-8. but before that I tried ANSI encoding with a different code.

Comment: Thanks Marc, but iv'e tried this syntax before, and I had the same problem. maybee you know (or anyone else knows) the full and exact syntax when I want to read a UTF-8 file and read all it's text - line by line.

Comment: Could it be that you don't have any Hebrew fonts on the device? Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593503/using-hebrew-with-the-android-emulator/3174891#3174891

Comment: No, I have hebrew fonts ,because when I'm writing hebrew directly to te textView there isn't any problem.