# Set RTL language in a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to set Right-To-Left language in my TextView.
I've read here :
[Using hebrew with the android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593503/using-hebrew-with-the-android-emulator)

that I should use "\u200F" character mode.
So I've tried to set it in my listview adapter:

```
holder.tvTitle.setText("\u200F" + articleRow.title);
```

but it doesn't seem to have any affect.
My text is set to right gravity.
What can be the problem ?

Thanks in advance.